# Vim popup window not showing on successive events

Tags: vim

I have the following plugin I wrote to test popup windows

"plugin/morning/morning.vim"

```
augroup morning_command_line_popup
    autocmd!
    au CmdlineLeave * call morning#close()
    au CmdlineEnter * call morning#open()
    au CmdlineChanged * call morning#update()
augroup END
```

"autoload/morning.vim"

```
function morning#open()
    let opt = {}
    let opt.border = []
    let opt.minwidth = &columns / 3
    let g:morning_window_handle = popup_create(":echo 'hi'", opt)
endfunction

function morning#close()
    call popup_close(g:morning_window_handle)
endfunction

function morning#update()
    call popup_show(g:morning_window_handle)
endfunction
```

The first time I enter the command line, the popup window appears. Every successive time that I enter the command line, it doesn't appear. I know the events are being fired and the functions are being called because if I put `echom` commands in the functions the messages show. Anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if I `redraw` after showing the popup window, it seems to work consistently. I don't know if there's a reason why it won't redraw normally, or if doing this is extremely inefficient. This also has the side effect of overwriting `wildmenu`.

```
function morning#open()
    let opt = {}
    let opt.border = []
    let opt.minwidth = &columns / 3
    let g:morning_window_handle = popup_create(":echo 'hi'", opt)
    redraw
endfunction

function morning#close()
    call popup_close(g:morning_window_handle)
endfunction

function morning#update()
    call popup_settext(g:morning_window_handle, string(getcmdline()))
    call popup_show(g:morning_window_handle)
    redraw
endfunction
```